# url issues - relationship field with multiple channels

Tags: channel-entries, templates, relationships, url-title

I've got 2 channels, "message" and "message series" and I'm using a relationship field in the message channel to tie a sermon to a sermon series.  My template group is called media, and there is a media-view template that I'm trying to use to display a listing of all the sermons in a particular sermon series.  My issue is that when I click one of the sermon series to view the sermons in that particular series, it goes to a blank page with my header and footer on it, but no content.  It's trying to go to media/media-view/name-of-sermon-series.  However, when I view the rendered template from the EE control panel, it displays correctly at media/media-view.  That would be fine except, if I change my link to go to media/media-view, and click the link to a sermon series, it always takes me to the same sermon series page, regardless of which link I'm clicking.  Something in my code is off, and I can't for the life of me figure out what it is.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

here's my code from my media template:

```
{embed="embeds/html_header" page_title="Media"}
{exp:channel:entries channel="message_series" orderby="date" sort="asc" limit="10" paginate="bottom" {gv_param_disable_default}}    

        <li class="section-post">
            <a class="message-link" href="{path=media/media-view/{url_title}}"><img src="{series_image}" class="message-image" title="{title}" alt="{title}">
            <span class="mask">
                <img src="{site_url}/images/interface/ico-search.png">
            </span>
            </a>
            <a href="{path=media/media-view/{url_title}}"><h2 class="inline-header">{title}</a></h2><br />
            <p><i>{series_begin_date format='%Y'}{if series_association != ""}, Series{/if} </i></p>

        </li>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

and here's my code from my media/media-view template:

```
{embed="embeds/html_header" page_title="{exp:channel:entries channel="message"}{title}                {/exp:channel:entries}"}
{exp:channel:entries channel="message" limit="1" {gv_param_disable_default}}


                    {series_association}
                    <h1 class="section-header">{series_association:title}</h2>
                    {snp_social_share}
                    <div class="section-post">
                    <p>{series_association:series_summary}</p>
                    <img src="{series_association:series_image}" class="drop-shadow message-image" title="{series_association:title}" alt="{series_association:title}">
                    <br /><br />
                    {/series_association}   
            {/exp:channel:entries}      
                <ul>
            {exp:channel:entries channel="message" orderby="date" sort="asc" {gv_param_disable_default}}
                    <li class="media-view">
                        <h2><u>{title}</u> - <i><h5>{message_date format='%F %d %Y'}</h5></i></h2> 
                        <p>{if message_speaker}<i>Speaker:</i> {message_speaker}{/if}
                        <p>{if message_scripture}<i>Scripture Reference:</i> {message_scripture}{/if}
                        <p>{message_summary}</p>
                        <audio src="{message_audio}" preload="none" />
                        <h5>{message_date format="%F %j, %Y"}</h5>
                    <li>
                    <br />
            {/exp:channel:entries}
                </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try changing the message tag to the following:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="message" limit="1" dynamic="no" url_title="{segment_3}" {gv_param_disable_default}}
```

This should disable any "guessing" EE might be doing and force it to match the entry you're actually requesting.